# Facebook pixel missing content_ids

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-pixel

I am trying to use Facebook pixels AddToCart but get an error that says:

> Missing content_ids or contents from 'AddToCart'.

I am using a click handler to try run this code. So, when the user clicks on 'add to cart' I have some hardcoded values for now.

```
            fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
                content_ids: [ 21 ],
                content_type: 'product',
                value: 12,
                currency: 'USD'
            });
```

I do not get an error in console or any clues there.

Found this on their website:

```
  fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes', 
    content_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes',
    content_ids: ['1234'],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 4.99,
    currency: 'USD' 
  });
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add `contents` as well, because that contains the actual _quantity_ info.

Comment: @CBroe, I just updated my question with some code I found on Facebook. I don't see the `contents` you are referring to but I do see `content_name` which I don't have. Do you think it could be that?

Comment: All the parameters are documented, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference `contents` would be required for Dynamic Ads for example.